# Installing Ruby GSL on Heroku

Tags: heroku, gsl, gamma-distribution

We are using a the distribution gem for calculating a gamma distribution and because we specifically require the gamma quantile method, we also require gsl

```
https://github.com/sciruby/distribution
https://github.com/SciRuby/rb-gsl
```

This works fine locally but we are trying to push this to heroku and running into immediate problems.

From the looks of things, we require a gsl buildpack which are only supported up to version 1.16 of gsl. There doesn't appear to be a gsl buildpack for the current version 2.1. Installing GSL 1.16 locally appears to be really problematic and we haven't been successful doing this either.

Looking into this further, it looks like we would need to create a binary for the curret  version which would need to be hosted on AWS. Seems a bit extreme for what is basically two methods.

Either, we need help building a buildpack or need an alternative to these two specific methods.

```
Distribution::Gamma.quantile
Distribution::Gamma::Ruby_.cdf
```

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Please read the tag descriptor before using a tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [installation instructions](https://github.com/SciRuby/rb-gsl#installation) for `rb-gsl` say (slightly modified for clarity):

> Ruby/GSL may be installed as a Ruby Gem by simply running
>
> ```
> gem install gsl
> ```
>
> Note that the GSL libraries must already be installed before Ruby/GSL can be installed:
>
> Debian/Ubuntu: `libgsl0-dev`

Rather than a custom buildpack, I suspect you can get away with simply depending on the `gsl` gem and adding [the apt buildpack](https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/heroku/heroku-buildpack-apt) for the Ubuntu dependency:

1. Add the apt buildpack early in your list of buildpacks, e.g. by running

   ```
   heroku buildpacks:add --index 1 heroku-community/apt
   ```
2. Create an `Aptfile` in the root directory of your repository and list the Ubuntu packages you require inside it, e.g.

   ```
   libgsl0-dev
   ```
3. Commit the `Aptfile` and redeploy

Note that the apt buildpack does not do dependency resolution. If `libgsl0-dev` requires other packages, you'll need to explicitly list them as well.

Comment: I think I might be in love with you Chris. 
Thank you so so much! Worked perfectly